# Problem with get path to a subfolder in main bundle in AVPlayer

Tags: swift, avplayer

I'm improving the code I have for my project.

I stuck with the process of calling videos by subfolders because the code reads all the mp4 files, it finds.

Applying different codes that I have found on the internet, but I end up breaking all the code without success. I would appreciate help or advice in this regard.

Attached image that shows the location of folders with the different videos that I would like to separate my view basic and intermediate folder
    import UIKit
    import AVKit
    import AVFoundation

```
class BasicLevel: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate{

    var videoArray = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoTableView: UITableView!

    var videoVC = AVPlayerViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        videoTableView.delegate = self
        videoTableView.dataSource = self

        videoView.addSubview(videoVC.view)
        videoVC.view.frame = videoView.frame
        videoVC.showsPlaybackControls = false

        let filemanager = FileManager.default
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!

        let allItems = try? filemanager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)

        for singleItem in allItems! {
            if singleItem.hasSuffix("mp4") {
                videoArray.append(singleItem)
            }
        }

        if videoArray.count > 0 {
            playTopVideo(value: 0)
        }
    }

    func playTopVideo(value: Int) {
        let nameComponent = videoArray[value].components(separatedBy: ".")
        let name = nameComponent[0]

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "mp4")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)


        videoVC.player = AVPlayer(url: url)

        videoVC.player?.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **you** are responsible for creating the directory structure of the bundle so don't mess it up.

Secondly use the URL related API.

For example put all mp4 files in a subdirectory named `videos`. It's crucial that you create a real **blue** folder rather than a group (yellow) folder.

This would reduce your code to

```
var videoArray = [URL]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    videoTableView.delegate = self
    videoTableView.dataSource = self

    videoView.addSubview(videoVC.view)
    videoVC.view.frame = videoView.frame
    videoVC.showsPlaybackControls = false

    videoArray = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "mp4", subdirectory: "videos")!
    playTopVideo(value: 0)
}

func playTopVideo(value: Int) {
    let videoURL = videoArray[value]
    videoVC.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    videoVC.player?.play()
}
```

Comment: I'm left with an error when showing in the tableview, it shows me the extension;.  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "videocell", for: indexPath)
        
        let videoName = videoArray[indexPath.row]
        let nameComponent = videoName.components(separatedBy: "-")
        cell.textLabel?.text = nameComponent[0]

Comment: To show only the name of an URL use `let videoName = videoArray[indexPath.row].deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent`